# setTimeout || requestAnimationFrame animation not smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

The showLoop animation is smooth but sometimes skips frames and messes up, using css3 animation ease-in property.

```
 function showLoop() {
     setTimeout(function () {
         $spans.eq(i).css('opacity', 1);
         i = i + 1;
         if (i < count) {
             showLoop();
             if (i == count - 2) delay = 800;
         }
     }, 400);
 }
 showLoop();


 function draw() {
     setTimeout(function () {
         if (i < count) {
             requestAnimationFrame(draw);
             //$spans.eq(i).css('opacity', 1);
             $spans.eq(i).fadeIn(400);
             i = i + 1;
             if (i == count.length - 1) {
                 delay = 800;
             }
             if (i == count) {
                 $spans.css('opacity', 0);
                 $(background).css('background', 'rgba(222, 88, 39, .0)');
             }
         }
     }, delay);
 }
```

The requestanimationframe just isnt smooth enough. Am Im doing this the wrong way, should I be doing this via jquery .animation?

Comment: Can you provide a working example on http://jsbin.com/

Comment: yes jQuery recomended! if you want to stick with plain js then get the timerValue from `setTimeout`(s) and clear them using `clearTimeout`

Comment: you should look into `delta time` when it comes to creating smoother animations. [read this](https://gist.github.com/joelambert/1002116)